# Android studio path error

Tags: android-studio

I'm getting this error:

```
Config path'C:\Program Files(x86)\Android\android-studio\config' is invalid.  
If you have modified the 'idea.config.path' property please make sure it is correct,      
otherwise please re-install the IDE.
```

I even re-installed the IDE, however, it doesn't work!

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Bug report: [Config file reported as invalid when installed for all users](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61067)

Answer (score 38):

Open this file C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\bin\idea.properties.

You will see something like this

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE config folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#idea.config.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudioPreview/config

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE system folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#idea.system.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudioPreview/system
....etc
```

remove the # sign from those specific options and save it.

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE config folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.config.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudioPreview/config
....etc
```

restart the android-stuido again.

Comment: in case of Linux what to do

Answer (score 20):

Run as administrator. The default locations for \config and \system are under c:\Program Files, which Windows won't let common software write to. Karu's solution moves the \config and \system folders to the current users directory, which is fair-er game.

Answer (score 11):

I try not to run software as Administrator unless it's really necessary and in this case it's not.

Do as @karu says, but go ahead and uncomment the top 4 paths in the *idea.properties* file to stop the next error that you would get about an invalid System path and so on...

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\bin\idea.properties**

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE config folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.config.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudioPreview/config

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE system folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.system.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudioPreview/system

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to user installed plugins folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.plugins.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudioPreview/config/plugins

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE logs folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.log.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudioPreview/system/log
```

Save this file and restart Android Studio and you should have no more errors.

*Note: I imagine that they will solve this issue in future versions but this is part of the fun you get for joining in on a project still in Beta (currently v0.2)*

Comment: Working well for Android Studio 1.4. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

uncomment the **idea.config.path** and what ever the options available in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\bin\idea.properties file

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue, just wait 5 minutes and it will start properly.

Comment: It does not start after 5 minutes for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and the reason for my issue was my hard disk has run out of free space (installing new android versions had filled up my hard disk without me knowing :) ) . cleaning up the hard and getting some free space fixed my issue

Answer (score 2):

My Problem was that my laptop storage was full, once the space was freed, this error got resolved.

Comment: its working, i just removed avd files and make the trash empty .

Answer (score 1):

Just run Android Studio as administrator .......

Comment: Flagged has 'low-quality'. Can you elaborate your answer ? Any clue where you got this idea, information ? Any 'bug-report' link ?

Comment: Also, another answer already exists saying to run as administrator. If you agree with that answer, it's best to upvote it rather than creating a new answer.

Comment: Please check this as an answer. Its correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Android Studio and reinstall using the default settings (install for the current user only).

Android Studio is only half baked, and support for sharing an installation across multiple users is among the features that are still in the oven.

**Note:** To work around [another bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61065) with multi-user installation, you have to "help" the uninstaller by manually deleting `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Android Studio`. Otherwise, after the reinstall, you'll have two sets of Start Menu icons.

Comment: Is there no way other than re-installation ?

Answer (score 0):

Just Run it as Administrator

issue was about permissions

Worked for me :)

Comment: I want access to all users. What can I do ?

Comment: Sounds like a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17949413).

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the temp file I solved the same problem.

Just go to Run, type "%temp%", hit enter, and delete all the files under the Temp directory.

Answer (score -1):

Configure your shortcut (Advanced options) to run always as administrator , you 'll save some seconds each time.

Answer (score -1):

I searched for different ways to fix this issue with android studio, and I've found the solution.

My problem was that Windows Accounts Manager locked my profile folder to do anything, just change permissions to that folder and it will work

Just do this in your profile folder and select your user

[image: Just do this in your profile folder and select your user]

After this, run Android Studio, and voila! Hope this help!