# Invalid Config Path

Tags: android-studio

Android studio is giving this "Invalid Config Path" error. I've already tried this: [Android studio path error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390213/android-studio-path-error) and reinstalled it, it still doesn't seem to work.

See this: http://prntscr.com/9zufj4

Also, I have renamed the username from "Tanuj Singh" to "Tanuj" and this might be a path issue, anybody knows how to fix?

Comment: Please write your error here as text, don't rely on an external image hosting service and provide the people helping you with text to work with.

Answer (score 0):

i also had the same probelm. Try changing or creating a new Path in the system variables and assign it to your java version and the directory as shown

[image]