# android studio startup error - config is invalid

Tags: android

I had installed Android Studio few months back. It was working fine till yesterday. Windows made some automatic update. Then, I started getting an error if I try to start Android Studio:

> Config path'C:\Program Files(x86)\Android\android-studio\config' is invalid.
>   If you have modified the 'idea.config.path' property please make sure it is correct,
>   otherwise please re-install the IDE.

I searched on Stack Overflow and found some suggestions which had helped others - [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390213/android-studio-path-error)

But this is not helping me. In my copy of the file `C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\bin\idea.properties`, the lines

```
 #idea.config.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudioPreview/config
 #idea.system.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudioPreview/system
```

were missing. (I have copied these here from the other link with answers).

I have tried

- Uninstall the installation and reinstall it
- Running Android Studio as administrator
- Manually opening the idea.properties file as administrator, adding
  the 2 lines for config and system, then saving file and restarting
  Android Studio.

But the same error persists. Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled once more. Then, again ran the installation with "run as administrator" privilege. After this, if I start Android studio with "run as administrator" privilege, then it starts up. If I run it normally (non-administrator) it still runs into the same error.