# Failed to create JVM: error code 60; JVM path C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jvm

I searched for speeding up Android Studio and applying this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up) and after that android studio starts throwing this error. I searched a lot but couldn't find the proper solution. I also check JAVA_HOME path, Test on console (C:\Users\abc>echo %JAVA_HOME%) it's working fine and JDK is also 64 bit. Even I also tried by reinstall android studio and JDK again but the error continues.

I am using windows 10 Education, 64 bit OS.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: I have [answered on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532284/5376073) what was working for me.

Answer (score 0):

i just delete studio64.exe vm options from .AndroidStudiox.x folder and start androidstudio , it will work for me.
After that if you will get any error then follow this link:
[Android studio path error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390213/android-studio-path-error)